# matplotlib separating scatterplot points and creating a divisionary curve

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to create a divisionary curve on a scatter plot in matplotlib that would divide my scatterplot according to marker size.

The (x,y) are phi0 and phi0dot and I'm coloring/sizing according a to third variable 'e-folds'. I'd like to draw an 'S' shaped curve that divides the plot into small, black markers and large, cyan markers.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mCv0.png) is a sample scatterplot run with a very few number of points for an example. Ultimately I will run with tens of thousands of points of data such that the divisionary would be much finer and more obviously 'S' shaped. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VyK9.png) is roughly what I have in mind.

My code thus far looks like this:

```
# Set up the PDF
pdf_pages = PdfPages(outfile)
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"

# Create the canvas
canvas = plt.figure(figsize=(14.0, 14.0), dpi=100)
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)

for a, phi0, phi0dot, efolds in datastore:
    if efolds[-1] > 65:
        plt.scatter(phi0[0], phi0dot[0], s=200, color='aqua')
    else:
        plt.scatter(phi0[0], phi0dot[0], s=30, color='black')

# Apply labels
plt.xlabel(r"$\phi_0$")
plt.ylabel(r"$\dot{\phi}_0$")

# Finish the file
pdf_pages.savefig(canvas)
pdf_pages.close()
print("Finished!")
```

[This type of separation](http://www.astroml.org/examples/datasets/plot_sdss_line_ratios.html) is very akin to what I'd like to do, but don't see immediately how I would extend this to my problem. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Will the plot always be *split* vertically (roughly)?

Comment: more or less -- it usually takes on the shape I drew without the cut back to the right towards the top.

Comment: Please include enough example data to use for testing. - [mcve]

Comment: I am in the middle of a 12 hour run to collect data for the tens of thousands of points scatter plot and cannot provide data at the moment. However, if you have any ideas on how one would draw this line in theory with an arbitrary scatter plot with a clear division of points, I'd love to hear your thoughts. Will upload data for this toy model when my script finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the separation line between the differently classified points is a simple contour line along the threshold value.

Here I'm assuming classification takes values of `0` or `1`, hence one can draw a `contour` along `0.5`,

```
ax.contour(x,y,clas, [0.5])
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some data on a grid
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(20), np.arange(10))
z = np.sin(y+1) + 2*np.cos(x/5) + 2


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Threshold; values above the threshold belong to another class as those below.
thresh = 2.5
clas = z > thresh
size = 100*clas + 30*~clas

# scatter plot
ax.scatter(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), s = size.flatten(), c=clas.flatten(), cmap="bwr")
# threshold line
ax.contour(x,y,clas, [.5], colors="k", linewidths=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]